# If I remove the node.js log file, how to create one?

Tags: node.js

I remove the node.js log file like this.

```
cd /var/log
rm node.log
```

And now I create a log file named "node.log", but the file is not written by node.js.
How should I do? Thanks!!

Comment: Restart node? It is probably still writing to the old, deleted file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node will continue to write to the old (unlinked, but not yet deleted, because it is still open) log file.

Easiest way would be to restart node.